# Font Style does not change after adding style

Tags: html, css, fonts, styles

I tried to change the font to a `<h1>` tag in bootstrap css; here is the 
original code:

```
<h1 class="text-center"> My Site </h1>
```

I tried the following:

```
<h1 class="text-center" style=font-family: "Arial";> My Site </h1>
<h1 class="text-center" style=font-family: Aria;> My Site </h1>
```

However, none of which worked. I've tried with several basic fonts too, such as Verdana, Times New Roman, Courier etc.I very much appreciate it if someone can help me with my problem here.

Comment: you didn't include any code

Answer (score 1):

The way you change a font in CSS is by doing this:

```css
h1.t {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  }
h1.a {
  font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
h1.c {
  font-family: "Calibri", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
```

```html
<h1 class="t">Times New Roman</h1>
<h1 class="a">Arial</h1>
<h1 class="c">Calibri</h1>
```

There you go, you just need to know the family information, and you didn't have all the family info in there.

Answer (score 1):

HTML attributes values which are not delimited by quote characters cannot have spaces in them. Add quotes.

```
<h1 class="text-center" style="font-family: Arial;"> My Site </h1>
```

This would have been picked up if you have [used a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).

NB: A stylesheet is prefered over style attributes. You might want to read [an introductory guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/How_CSS_works).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
<h1 class="text-center" style="font-family: "Arial";"> My Site </h1>
```

Comment: Why should they try that one? What did you change? Why should it make a difference?

Comment: (Hint: It won't make a difference. `font-family:` is invalid CSS (the value is missing, and the whole thing is invalid HTML).

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

The short answer to your question is that your HTML is invalid. Here is the quick and dirty solution.

```
<h1 class="text-center" style="font-family: Arial;"> My Site </h1>
```

This is called *inline styling* and it's generally frowned upon for several reasons, but that's outside the scope of this question.

### Problems with the first example

#### Your code:

```
<h1 class="text-center" style=font-family: "Arial";> My Site </h1>
```

The quotes should contain all of the css in your style attribute. e.g., `style="font-family: Arial;"`

### Problems with the second example

#### Your code:

```
<h1 class="text-center" style=font-family: Aria;> My Site </h1>
```

Again, the quotes need to contain the style within your style attribute. It also looks like you dropped the "l" from "Arial" (typo).